# Group Date Range from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, group-by

I want to group a table based off another tables date range.

I am trying to do the following query where I join a table, `Actuals`, which has a `StartDate`.

I want to group its `Amount`s by Fiscal Months which have `StartDate` and `EndDate` and where the `Actual.StartDate` is between the `FiscalMonthsCalendarOptions` Start and End dates. I can't do strait months (which would be an easy group by of `GROUP BY DATEPART(month, act.StartDate), act.LinkingId`) which is what is making this hard.

I attempted the following but obviously you can group on a table alias. I believe the right way to do this is with a `partition by` and maybe using a `lag` operator, but I couldn't get it working.

```
SELECT 
    act.LinkingId,
    SUM(act.Amount) as AmountTotal,
    CASE 
        WHEN act.StartDate BETWEEN fco.StartDate AND fco.EndDate 
           THEN fco.StartDate
           ELSE act.StartDate
    END AS FiscalStartDate
FROM 
    [Actuals] act
INNER JOIN 
    FiscalMonthsCalendarOptions fco ON 1 = 1 
WHERE 
    act.Amount <> 0
GROUP BY 
    FiscalStartDate, act.LinkingId
```

I made a quick example table with the example data and expected result

```
DECLARE @actuals TABLE (LinkingId int, StartDate datetime, Amount decimal(18,4))
INSERT INTO @actuals(LinkingId, StartDate, Amount)
VALUES (1, '2021-01-01', 5),
(1, '2021-01-15', 3),
(2, '2021-01-01', 5),
(2, '2021-01-30', 4),
(2, '2021-02-05', 2)

DECLARE @fiscalMonthsCalendarOptions TABLE (StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, Code varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @fiscalMonthsCalendarOptions (StartDate, EndDate, Code)
VALUES ('2020-12-30', '2021-1-29', 'January'),
('2021-1-30', '2021-2-28', 'Feburary')

-- RESULT DESIRED: (LinkingId, Amount, StartDate)
-- (1, 8, 2020-12-30)
-- (2, 5, 2020-12-30)
-- (2, 6, 2021-1-30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to join the calendar table on the `act.StartDate` so then you don't have to mess around with the `partition by`

```
SELECT 
    act.LinkingId,
    SUM(act.Amount) as AmountTotal,
    fco.StartDate
FROM @actuals act
INNER JOIN @fiscalMonthsCalendarOptions fco on act.StartDate between fco.StartDate AND fco.EndDate
GROUP BY fco.StartDate, act.LinkingId
```